# How to group column into one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to group columns into one?

I have a df like:

| item | price1 | price2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 1 | 3 |
| Second | 2 | 4 |

I want to create a new df like:

| price |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |

Answer (score 0):

You can use the append function of pandas series. Assuming that you do not care about the indexes, this will work :

```
df['price1'].append(df['price2'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only use the columns that contain the word price, using `filter(like='price')`, and then `stack()`, and finally, rename the column to 'price':

```
df.filter(like='price').stack().reset_index()[[0]].rename(columns={0: 'price'})
```

Similar approach with `pd.concat()`:

```
pd.concat([df['price1'],df['price2']],axis=0).to_frame().rename(columns={0: 'price'})
```

Both give back:

```
   price
0      1
1      3
2      2
3      4
```

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way would be :

```
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame({'price1': [4, 3, 2],
                  'price2': [1, 5, 6]})

final = pd.DataFrame({'price': x['price1'].to_list() + x['price2'].to_list()})
```